# Optional character in input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask

How do I specify an optional character in an input mask?

I found this masked input plugin http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ and these mask definitions.

```
$.mask.definitions['g']="[ ]";
$.mask.definitions['h']="[aApP]";
$.mask.definitions['i']="[mM]";
$.mask.definitions['2']="[0-1]";
$.mask.definitions['6']="[0-5]";
new_mask = "29:69";
$("#txtTime").mask(new_mask);
```

This defines an input mask for a 12 hour time format, e.g. 11:00.  I'd like to allow the user to specify only one digit for the "hour".  Instead of having to type 01:00, the user should be able to type 1:00.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `?` for optional characters so in your case you should use "`2?9:69`".

Comment: But this still doesn't allow the user to specify only one character for the hour.  When I click out of the input field, the mask puts the minutes for the missing hour digit.

Comment: Good catch, this seems like a bug in the plugin. Unfortunately, I don't know of a good solution for it unless you modify the plugin itself.

Answer (score 4):

Quote and example from [the page](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) you linked to in your question:

> You can have part of your mask be optional. Anything listed after '?'
>   within the mask is considered optional user input. The common example
>   for this is phone number + optional extension.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$.mask.definitions['g']="[0-9 ]";`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem I am trying to solve for variable currency amounts ($0.00 - $10000.00), and I don't really understand how the plugin is working.

On the one hand, the `$.mask.definitions['symbol'] = '???'` bit looks like it's employing a regex fragment, based on the examples in the API reference, and somewhat confirmed by this part in the source, within the `mask` function's code:

```
$.each(mask.split(""), function (i, c) {
    if (c == '?') {
        len--;
        partialPosition = i;
    } else if (defs[c]) {
        tests.push(new RegExp(defs[c]));
        if (firstNonMaskPos == null)
            firstNonMaskPos = tests.length - 1;
    } else {
        tests.push(null);
    }
});
```

...On the other, a mask definition of `[]|[0-9]` does not work (I am attempting to do empty string or 0-9, for those not literate in regex.)  For reference, I am attempting to build a mask to fulfill the 0.00-10000.00 condition like `oooo9.99`, where `o` is `[]|[0-9]`.

Since the code confirms that this is based upon regexes, the null or range pattern should be working but aren't; this is a more obscure bug in the mask framework.  Unless *I* am the one trying to do something incorrectly, which is also possible...